# I'm trying to get data from local data with pinia and nuxt, and it can't seam to get the end point, what's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, pinia

I'm trying to get data from local data with pinia and nuxt, and it can't seam to get the end point, what's wrong with my code?

I'm new to Vue, Nuxt and Pinia, I have been following some tutorial, but I can't get to get data from the end point, here is my code.

#stores/blogStore.js

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const usePostStore = defineStore('post', {
    state: () => ({
        posts: [],
        loading: false,
        error: null
    }),
    getters: {
        postCount: (state) => state.posts.length,
        draftPosts: (state) => state.posts.filter((post) => post.status === 'draft'),
        publishedPosts: (state) => state.posts.filter((post) => post.status === 'published'),
        isDraft: (state, id) => state.posts.find((post) => post.id === id)?.status === 'draft',
        truncatedPosts: (state) => state.posts.map((post) => post.content.substring(0, 20) + '...'),
    },
    actions: {
        async getPosts() {
            this.loading = true
            console.log(this.loading)
            const api = "http://localhost:3000/posts"
            const res = await fetch(api)
            console.log
            if (!res.ok) {
                this.error = res.statusText
                return;
            }
            const data = await res.json();
            this.posts = data;
            this.loading = false;
        },
    },
});
```

#app.vue

```
<template>
<div v-if="store.loading">
    Loading ...
</div>
<div>
    <div> You have {{ store.postCount }} Blogs </div>
    <div v-for="post in store.posts" :key="post.id">
    <div>{{ post.title }}</div>

    <div>Views: {{ post.view_count }}</div>
    <br />
    </div>
</div>

</template>

<script setup>
import { usePostStore } from './stores/blogStore'
const store = usePostStore()


</script>
```

I have tried several back end like local json-server and django rest framework with no results but when I add the data inside the posts:[] it's correctly displaying the data in the html.
How can  I successfully fetch data from an endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `store.getPosts()` on the scripts setup loaded the data like

```
<script setup>
import { usePostStore } from './stores/blogStore'
const store = usePostStore()
store.getPosts()

</script>
```

this did the magic.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is with the fake endpoint you're trying to interact with.

Try this endpoint `https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts` which is suited for testing purposes!

Or maybe this endpoint `https://dummyjson.com/posts` with many information to interact with!

Comment: This is quite good information but I have tried them too, it is not displaying on my app

Comment: you need, when the component is mounted, to call the *getPosts* method, something like 
```js
import { usePostStore } from './stores/blogStore'
const store = usePostStore()

mounted(() => store.getPosts())

```